# boost::interprocess::managed_windows_shared_memory crashes on VC11

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2012

I have the following simple program:

```
#include <boost\interprocess\managed_windows_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost\interprocess\shared_memory_object.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main ()
{
    managed_windows_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 655360);
    return 0;
}
```

It crashes with the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6B7741664 in Server.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.
```

This happens only for the Release build in VC11. (VC10 is fine). Looking at the call stack, it is happening at rebalance_after_insertion() in boost\intrusive\rbtree_algorithms.hpp. Did anyone face the similar issue?

Comment: The stack frame is getting corrupted, the compiler didn't allocate enough space for the boost object.  By far the most common reason is you linking the wrong version or the wrong build of boost.  Like the one you built with VC10.  Or the debug build.

Comment: double checked the build, but it's getting the right version of boost.

Comment: I have the same issue, and I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct version of boost. It also only happens with the '/O2' optimization flag.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone would encounter this, the problem seems to be code generation-related with a specific version of boost (in my case v 1.55.0). It also only happens in a release-configuration and when applying optimization (i.e. '/O1', '/O2' or '/Ox'). Using Boost v.1.58 solved the problem.